# PDF in Iframe is overlapped other element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf, iframe

I have a screen where I need to show pdf/html .So I am making use of an iframe content to show the PDF or HTML in it.and whenever needed i need to show a popup on top masking the whole screen. This is working cool in all the places.

Problem is , only in Internet Explorer, if PDF is there in iframe content, the masking is not coming on top of the pdf, instead pdf overlaps the masking , popups,dropdowns.

Please let us know how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This also seems to happen in Firefox too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solve the problem. What you have to do is make iframe visibility hidden when you want to     show masking on the page.